# Sort() "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, sorting

Okay i got some issue with the `Collection.sort(myintarray);` line... it says `cannot find symbol` trying to make it sort the list so the lowest number in array come first.

```
package uppgift.pkg1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author Fredrik
 *
 */
public class Uppgift1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Anrop av metod
        skapaArray();
    }

    public static void skapaArray() {
        List<Integer> myintarray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int ints = 0;
        int size = 1;

        while (ints < size) {
            myintarray.add(ints);
            ints++;
        }
        Collection.sort(myintarray);
        System.out.println(myintarray.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html):

```
java.util.Collections;
```

and:

```
Collections.sort(myintarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Collections.sort(myintarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a collection in Java is easy, just use the Collections.sort(Collection) to sort your values.

You can do

```
Collections.sort(myintarray);
```

instead of

```
Collection.sort(myintarray);
```

Comment: If that solves your problem.Mark it as answer.Happy coding user3086529 :)